# Installing Heroku – Problems With Locking

Tags: linux, ubuntu, heroku

I'm trying to install Heroku CLI under instruction from the Odin Project.
I followed their instructions and entered into terminal in Linux:

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

It appears to be installing but then the error message which appears is the following:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I have no idea what to do with this information. (I typed "no" in response but that had no effect.) Does anyone out there know how to get past this?

ps. I have entered "heroku version" afterwards, but the only response is:

```
heroku: command not found
```

I'm stuck on this early stage because of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that you're unable to create the lock for the `apt` package manager. Unless there's another process trying to install packages on the machine, the other option is that you don't have the necessary rights.

In fact, your error comes most probably from the fact that you're running the command

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

as an unprivileged user. You need to run it as root.

Comment: Thanks dr01, How do I run the command "as root"?

Comment: Switch to the root user via `su -` or `sudo -i`, then run the command.

Comment: I tried that now but I receive the following response. (I am the superuser and my login works in every other scenario that i have encountered): marc@marc-VirtualBox:~$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure

Comment: marc@marc-VirtualBox:~$ su -i
su: invalid option -- 'i'

Comment: Could it be you mixed up the commands? Now try `sudo -i wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh` and give your usual login passwort on prompt.

Comment: Yes! That worked! Thank you so much both of you dr01 and Philippos! You guys are great!